# Center text to image that is a bulletpoint

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-pages, inline-styles

I'm using images as bulletpoints for my Github Pages (markdown files), as described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-create-an-unordered-list-with-image-bullets-in-HTML). Now, I'd like to center the text next to the image vertically. This is shown [here](https://techforluddites.com/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css) (cf. lower third of page), but **I have to do it with inline css** and cannot get it to work.

What I have so far:

```
<ul style="list-style-image: url('/assets/images/thumb.jpg'); padding-left: 120px;">
<li>I’m writing a long list item 1 so you can see what happens when the text wraps across multiple lines</li>
</ul>
```

gives me [image]

when I'd ideally want it to look like: [image]

I already tried setting the line height, but this results in weirdness when there's a linebreak, as is the case here. I read about flexbox, but am unsure how to use it inline. Any help is appreciated!

**I repeat: IT MUST BE INLINE !!**

Comment: why image on `ul`? Do you need the image on left and all items (`li`) on right? Or each `li` will contain a image and text?

Comment: instead of using the `list-style`, you can use simple css to achieve it.

Comment: I don't know much about CSS and HTML, this is just pieced together from what I found online. I want every list item to contain an image (as bullet point) and some text on the right of the image. @Abin, I think one cannot use a .css file as github markdown won't load it to prevent malware attacks

Comment: @masterBroesel, I just saw the reply. So you cannot use my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use in your HTML something like this:

```
<div class='list-item'>
  <img src='/assets/images/thumb.jpg' class='bullet-image'/>
  <p class='item-text'>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS you could add:

```
.list-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

That should do the trick. Then you can re-size the image as you like.

**EDIT:**

Another thing you can do, using inline styles is something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
      <img src='/assets/images/thumb.jpg' style=""/>
      <p> I’m writing a long list item 1 so you can see what happens when the text wraps across multiple lines </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then you should resize the image to the size you like by adding the width and height properties on the style attribute of the img element

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I specifically need to do it **inline**, as stated in the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want it inline could be: <div class='list-item' style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;'> 

Of course, this approach needs to use a div. I'm not sure if it works with the ul element. And sorry about the first and not inline answer

Comment: Please look at my edit and see if that works for you

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. The edit did the trick :) Thank you very much!